# MySqlDataReader reads data when there is sum(a+b) in the query

Tags: mysql

When I use this query

```
 ("SELECT id, at_date AS MyDate , nom, pax, SUM(prix*pax) AS somme, 
  SUM(pax) AS totpax
  FROM atelier ORDER BY " + Order_by + " " + SortDir + " LIMIT @Myid," + 
  PublicVariables.MySqlLimit, conn)
```

This gives an error here

```
 _listBox[1].Items.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["MyDate"]).ToString("d"));
```

Because there is NO ROWS int the table. Table is EMPTY.

But when I supress SUM(prix*pax) AS somme and SUM(pax) AS totpax from the query, reader does not read and no error occurs.

Is there any trick of MySql in there ?

I resolved the probleme by checking the table if there is any rows before calling this method but it's not what I like any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Group by clause for all non  aggregate function before order by clause:

```
group by id,MyDate,nom,pax
```

Comment: Do you know why. I don't need group but when I added GROUP BY id it begins not to read the empty table.(For the accepting I have to wait 2 minutes :))